# How to solve ' ANR Reason: executing service ' Error from service class?

Tags: android, service, build, android-mediaplayer, android-intentservice

I am using IntentService for background music. It will not working with above 7.1 (Nougat) devices.I want to play music on background, and also control play, pause and stop actions from application class. My code is..

Application class...

```
public class App extends Application {

    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
                .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new OneSignalNotificationReceivedHandler())
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new OneSignalNotificationOpenedHandler(getApplicationContext()))
                .init();

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
        intent = new Intent(App.this, BgSoundIntentServices.class);
        intent.setAction("");
        startService(intent);
    }


    private class MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

        private int numStarted = 0;

        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

            Log.e("APP",String.valueOf(appPrefDetails.getGameSound()));
            Log.e("APP",String.valueOf(activity.getLocalClassName()+" onActivityCreated"));
            if (appPrefDetails.getSound() && intent!=null) {
                if (activity.getLocalClassName().equalsIgnoreCase("Class1")) {
                    intent.setAction(BgSoundIntentServices.ACTION_PLAY);
                    startService(intent);
                }
            }
        }
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

        }public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

        }public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

        }
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

        }
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

        }
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

My Menifest file ..

```
  <service
     android:name="com.example.music.sample.BgSoundIntentServices">
    </service>
```

BgSoundIntentServices calss...

```
public class BgSoundIntentServices extends IntentService {

    public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.music.action.ACTION_PLAY";
    public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.music.action.ACTION_PAUSE";
    public static final String ACTION_FORCE_PAUSE = "com.example.music.action.ACTION_FORCE_PAUSE";
    public static final String ACTION_RESUME_PLAY = "com.example.music.action.ACTION_RESUME_PLAY";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.example.music.action.ACTION_STOP";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "com.example.music.action.STOP_SERVICE";

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private Handler fadeOutHandler;
    private Handler fadeInHandler;
    private boolean FORCE_PAUSE;
//    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private AppPrefDetails prefDetails;

    public BgSoundIntentServices() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

//        System.out.println("ACTIVITY_CREATE " + intent.getAction());

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (prefDetails==null){
            prefDetails=new AppPrefDetails(this);
        }
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            String intentAction = intent.getAction();
            switch (intentAction) {
                case ACTION_PLAY:

                    Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ACTION_PLAY"));
                    if (player == null) {
                        requestAudioFocusForMyApp(this);
                        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.app_bg);
                        player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                Play();
                                player.setLooping(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }else {
                        Play();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_PAUSE:
                    Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ACTION_PAUSE"));
                    Pause();
                    break;
                case ACTION_FORCE_PAUSE:
                    Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ACTION_FORCE_PAUSE"));
                    ForcePause();
                    break;
                case ACTION_RESUME_PLAY:
                    Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ACTION_RESUME_PLAY"));
                    ResumePlay();
                    break;
                case ACTION_STOP:
                    Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ACTION_STOP"));
                    StopPlayer();
                    break;
                case ACTION_STOP_SERVICE:
                    Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ACTION_STOP_SERVICE"));
                    StopService(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void Play() {
        if (player != null && requestAudioFocusForMyApp(this)) {
            Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" Play"));
//            player.start();
            FadeIn(player, 1000);
            FORCE_PAUSE = false;
        }
    }

    public void Pause() {
        if (player != null) {
            Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" Pause"));
            FadeOut(player, 1000);
//           player.pause();
            FORCE_PAUSE = false;
        }
    }

    public void ForcePause() {
        if (fadeInHandler != null) {
            fadeInHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeInHandler = null;
        }
        if (fadeOutHandler != null) {
            fadeOutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeOutHandler = null;
        }
        Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ForcePause"));
        player.pause();
        FORCE_PAUSE = true;

    }

    public void ResumePlay() {
        if (fadeInHandler != null) {
            fadeInHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeInHandler = null;
        }
        if (fadeOutHandler != null) {
            fadeOutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeOutHandler = null;
        }
        if (player != null && FORCE_PAUSE) {
            Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" ResumePlay"));
//            player.start();
            if (player.isPlaying()){
                player.pause();
            }
            FadeIn(player, 1000);
            FORCE_PAUSE = false;
        }
    }

    public void StopPlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" StopPlayer"));
                player.stop();
                player.release();
                player = null;
            } else {
                Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" StopPlayerRelease"));
                player.release();
                player = null;
            }
        }
        releaseAudioFocusForMyApp(this);
    }

    public void StopService(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("APP",String.valueOf("onStartCommand"+" StopService"));
        if (fadeInHandler != null) {
            fadeInHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeInHandler = null;
        }
        if (fadeOutHandler != null) {
            fadeOutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeOutHandler = null;
        }
        stopService(intent);
        releaseAudioFocusForMyApp(this);
    }

    public void FadeOut(final MediaPlayer player, final int duration) {
        final float deviceVolume = getDeviceVolume();
        if (fadeOutHandler != null) {
            fadeOutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeOutHandler = null;
        }
        if (fadeInHandler != null) {
            fadeInHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeInHandler = null;
        }
        fadeOutHandler = new Handler();
        fadeOutHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            private float time = duration;
            private float volume = 0.0f;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!player.isPlaying())
                    player.start();
                // can call h again after work!
                time -= 100;
                volume = (deviceVolume * time) / duration;
                player.setVolume(volume, volume);
                if (time > 0)
                    fadeOutHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                else {
                    player.pause();
//                    _player.release();
                    fadeOutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                }
            }
        }, 100); // 1 second delay (takes millis)


    }

    public void FadeIn(final MediaPlayer player, final int duration) {
        final float deviceVolume = getDeviceVolume();
        if (fadeInHandler != null) {
            fadeInHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeInHandler = null;
        }
        if (fadeOutHandler != null) {
            fadeOutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            fadeOutHandler = null;
        }
        fadeInHandler = new Handler();
        fadeInHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            private float time = 0.0f;
            private float volume = 0.0f;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!player.isPlaying())
                    player.start();
                // can call h again after work!
                time += 100;
                volume = (deviceVolume * time) / duration;
                player.setVolume(volume, volume);
                if (time < duration) {
                    fadeInHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                } else {
                    fadeInHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                }
            }
        }, 100); // 1 second delay (takes millis)

    }

    public float getDeviceVolume() {
        int volumeLevel = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        return (float) volumeLevel / maxVolume;
    }


    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

            switch (focusChange) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:  //RETURN TO CUT THE CALL
//                    Log.i("AUDIOFOCUS", "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
                    if (prefDetails.getSound() && player != null && !App.AppIsBackground() && FORCE_PAUSE) {
                        ResumePlay();
                    }
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:  //OTHER MEDIYA FOCUS
//                    Log.e("AUDIOFOCUS", "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");

                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT: //CALL FOCUS
//                    Log.e("AUDIOFOCUS", "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
                    if (prefDetails.getSound() && player != null && !App.AppIsBackground()) {
                        ForcePause();
                    }
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
//                    Log.e("AUDIOFOCUS", "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
                    // Lower the volume
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT:
//                    Log.i("AUDIOFOCUS", "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT");
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
//                    Log.i("AUDIOFOCUS", "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK");
                    // Play over existing audio
                    break;
            }
        }
    };



    private boolean requestAudioFocusForMyApp(Context context) {
        audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Request audio focus for playback
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void releaseAudioFocusForMyApp(final Context context) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

When am get debug build it showing below errors, app is not open, it shows app not responding..

```
06-06 16:15:34.546 1772-1787/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.music
PID: 14500
Reason: executing service com.example.music/.sample.BgSoundIntentServices
Load: 5.74 / 5.4 / 5.26
CPU usage from 92145ms to 0ms ago (2018-06-06 16:13:59.644 to 2018-06-06 16:15:31.789):
  22% 1772/system_server: 13% user + 8.4% kernel / faults: 62105 minor 2 major
  3.7% 559/surfaceflinger: 1.7% user + 2% kernel / faults: 509 minor
  2.8% 3576/com.google.android.gms: 2.1% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 12127 minor 37 major
  2.8% 456/logd: 1.1% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 194 minor
  2.2% 3170/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 1.6% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 6125 minor 13 major
  1.6% 14698/adbd: 0.5% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 6005 minor
  1% 1436/mediaserver: 0.7% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 49 minor
  1% 9989/kworker/u16:3: 0% user + 1% kernel
  0.4% 31702/com.android.vending: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 9114 minor 2 major
  0.9% 2599/com.android.systemui: 0.7% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3251 minor 1 major
  0.8% 11841/kworker/u16:4: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
  0.8% 358/mmc-cmdqd/0: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
  0.6% 10236/kworker/u16:8: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
  0.5% 540/healthd: 0% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1 minor
  0.5% 9914/logcat: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 40 minor
  0.4% 3356/com.miui.whetstone: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 962 minor 2 major
  0.3% 699/jbd2/dm-1-8: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
  0.4% 1437/netd: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 3666 minor
  0.1% 1432/zygote64: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 4816 minor
  0.3% 3435/com.miui.home: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3933 minor
  0.4% 3453/com.miui.securitycenter.remote: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3454 minor 2 major
  0.4% 2880/com.android.phone: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 726 minor 1 major
  0.3% 12250/kworker/u16:2: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
  0.3% 7479/mdss_fb0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
  0.3% 8667/com.microsoft.office.outlook: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1031 minor 1 major
  0.3% 558/servicemanager: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 47 minor
  0.2% 3862/com.miui.powerkeeper:service: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 878 minor 3 major
  0.2% 17441/com.xiaomi.discover: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4426 minor
  0.1% 109/system: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 177/kswapd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0.2% 877/msm_irqbalance: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 45 minor
  0% 15941/com.lenovo.anyshare.gps:mobi: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1659 minor 7 major
  0.1% 346/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 12503/kworker/4:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0.1% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 39/rcuop/4: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 1433/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2177 minor
  0.1% 29599/VosTXThread: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 422/ueventd: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
  0.1% 53/rcuop/6: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 10/rcuop/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 3304/com.miui.daemon: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 450 minor
  0.1% 36/ksoftirqd/4: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 557/lmkd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 25 minor
  0% 3757/com.lbe.security.miui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1300 minor
  0.1% 12977/kworker/5:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 29600/VosRXThread: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0.1% 13010/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 46/rcuop/5: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 25/rcuop/2: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 740/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 534 minor
  0% 3087/mcd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 32 minor
  0% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 8/rcu_sched: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 43/ksoftirqd/5: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 3149/com.xiaomi.xmsf: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 482 minor
  0% 29607/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 33 minor
  0% 18/rcuop/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 50/ksoftirqd/6: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 60/rcuop/7: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 210/hwrng: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 543/rmt_storage: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 38 minor
  0% 1434/audioserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 96 minor
  0% 2860/.dataservices: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 163 minor
  0% 3106/irq/180-408000.: 0% user + 0% kernel
  0% 1142
```

Please anyone help me..

Advance Thanks..

Comment: Show your `.sample.BgSoundIntentServices` class please

Comment: please check now.

Comment: anyone please help me.. build is playstore

Comment: finally this error will fixed.

Comment: see the answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279803/6477998]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks error will fixed,

error is, application class is creating multiple times so, intent will created multiple time so only show this ANR error.

now just am check intent is equal to null on before creating, its working fine.

like,

```
if(intent==null){
    intent = new Intent(App.this, BgSoundIntentServices.class);
    intent.setAction("");
    startService(intent);
}
```

its working for me.

thanks.